# Transform Curl Oauth2 to Python Script

Tags: python, curl, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, access-token

Below bash script works and returns a token.

```
curl -X POST --user <id>:<key> 'https://<name>.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

I would now like to generate a token via a Python script. I currently struggle with using requests library, but without success. Below generates Response 400 (bad request).

```
import requests
parameters = {"user":"<id>:<key>", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
response = requests.get("https://<name>.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials", params=parameters)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your usage of `requests`:

- Use `post()` instead of `get()`.
- Use an `auth` object to construct a basic auth header. (Or send credentials in the body)
- Remove the content type header; `requests` will set this for you.
- Take the grant_type out of the query string. This belongs in the request body.

---

While the documentation for the `/oauth2/token` endpoint says you need to send a basic auth header for `client_credentials` grant, it also works if you send the client id and secret in the request body (with no auth header).

As such, these python examples both work, and are essentially equivalent:

Credentials in request body:

```
import requests

url = 'https://<COGNITO_DOMAIN>.auth.<REGION>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token'
params = {
    "client_secret": "1ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc2b",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt"
}
response = requests.post(url, data=params)

print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Credentials in basic auth header:

```
import requests

url = 'https://<COGNITO_DOMAIN>.auth.<REGION>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token'
params = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
auth = ('7xxxxxxxxxxt', '1ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc2b')
r = requests.post(url, data=params, auth=auth)

print(r)
print(r.text)
```